# ErrorException: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"?

Tags: php, laravel, jobs, laravel-excel

Estoy trabajando con un Job en Laravel 5.2 y laravel-excel 2.1 para poder generar un reporte excel algo pesado (para mis pruebas uso pocos datos y aun asi ocurre el error).

Lo curioso es que si yo ejecuto directamente(sin job) el método para generar reporte, todo sale bien.

Pero si uso el Job con driver database o redis, me ocasiona el error:

**Laravel.log** *(lo pongo sin formato codigo por que no me acepta poner mucho codigo)*

local.DEBUG: - Se construyo la data
local.DEBUG: Fallo la ejecucion del Job
local.DEBUG: ErrorException: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did you mean to use "continue 2"? in /home/vagrant/code/efact/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Shared/OLE.php:288
    Stack trace:
    #0 /home/vagrant/code/efact/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Autoloader.php(79): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, '"continue" targ...', '/home/vagrant/c...', 288, Array)
    #1 /home/vagrant/code/efact/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Autoloader.php(79): require()
    #2 [internal function]: PHPExcel_Autoloader::load('PHPExcel_Shared...')
    #3 /home/vagrant/code/efact/vendor/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel5.php(169): spl_autoload_call('PHPExcel_Shared...')
    #4 /home/vagrant/code/efact/vendor/maatwebsite/excel/src/Maatwebsite/Excel/Writers/LaravelExcelWriter.php(402): PHPExcel_Writer_Excel5->save('/home/vagrant/c...')
    #5 /home/vagrant/code/efact/app/Services/ReporteContadorService.php(745): Maatwebsite\Excel\Writers\LaravelExcelWriter->store('xls')
    #6 /home/vagrant/code/efact/app/Jobs/ConstruirReportePesado.php(59): App\Services\ReporteContadorService->excelConcarServer(170, 183, '07', '2019')
    #7 [internal function]: App\Jobs\ConstruirReportePesado->handle()

Mi codigo es el siguiente:

**Mi Job:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Jobs\Job;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;

use App\Services\ReporteContadorService;
use App\SolicitudReporte;
use Log;

class ConstruirReportePesado extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels;

    protected $empresa;
    protected $tienda;
    protected $mes;
    protected $anio;
    protected $idSolicitud;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */

    public function __construct($empresa, $tienda, $mes, $anio, $id)
    {
        $this->empresa = $empresa;
        $this->tienda = $tienda;
        $this->mes = $mes;
        $this->anio = $anio;
        $this->idSolicitud = $id;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        echo "> Procesando reporte ...\n";

        $solicitud = SolicitudReporte::find($this->idSolicitud);

        try {
            Log::debug('************    CONSTRUYENDO REPORTE PESADO     ***********');
            Log::debug('- empresa   : '.$this->empresa);
            Log::debug('- tienda    : '.$this->tienda);
            Log::debug('- fecha     : '.$this->anio.'-'.$this->mes);
            Log::debug('- solicitud : '.$this->idSolicitud);


            $reporte = new ReporteContadorService;
            $reporte->excelConcarServer($this->empresa, $this->tienda, $this->mes, $this->anio);

            $solicitud->estado = 2;
            $solicitud->save();
        } catch (\Throwable $th) {
            Log::debug('Fallo la ejecucion del Job');
            echo "- Fallo la ejecucion del Job\n";
            Log::debug($th);
            $solicitud->estado = 0;
            $solicitud->save();
        }

        Log::debug('************        FIN DE PROCESO          ***********');
        echo "> Fin de proceso\n";
    }

     /**
     * Handle a job failure.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function failed()
    {
        Log::debug('El Job ha Fallado');
    }
}
```

**Mi Método que Construye el Reporte:**

```
public function excelConcarServer($empresa, $tienda, $mes, $anio)
    {
        $data = $this->construirDataConcar($empresa, $tienda, $mes, $anio);

        Log::debug('- Se construyo la data');

        Excel::create($empresa.' - REPORTE VENTAS '.$mes.'-'.$anio, function($excel) use($data, $mes, $anio) {

            $excel->setCreator('SAFEBILL')->setCompany('IMAGINATICS PERU');

            $excel->sheet('ventas '.$mes.'-'.$anio, function($sheet) use($data) {
                $sheet->fromArray($data);

                $title = array(
                    'Sub Diario', 
                    'Numero de Comprobante', 
                    'Fecha de Comprobante', 
                    'Código de Moneda', 
                    'Glosa Principal', 
                    'Tipo de Cambio', 
                    'Tipo de Conversion', 
                    'Flag de Conversion de Moneda', 
                    'Fecha Tipo de Cambio', 
                    'Cuenta Contable', 
                    'Código de Anexo', 
                    'Código de Centro de Costo', 
                    'Debe / Haber', 
                    'Importe Original', 
                    'Importe en Dólares', 
                    'Importe en Soles', 
                    'Tipo de Documento', 
                    'Número de Documento', 
                    'Fecha de Documento', 
                    'Fecha de Vencimiento', 
                    'Código de Area', 
                    'Glosa Detalle', 
                    'Codigo de Anexo Auxiliar', 
                    'Medio de Pago', 
                    'Tipo de Documento de Referencia', 
                    'Número de Documento Referencia', 
                    'Fecha Documento Referencia', 
                    'Base Imponible Documento Referencia', 
                    'IGV Documento Provision', 
                    'Tipo Referencia en estado MQ', 
                    'Número Serie Caja Registradora', 
                    'Fecha de Operacion', 
                    'Tipo de Tasa', 
                    'Tasa Detraccion/Percepción', 
                    'Importe Base Detraccion/Percepcion Dólares', 
                    'Importe Base Detraccion/Percepcion Soles', 
                    'Tipo Cambio para F'
                );

                $sheet->row(1, $title);

                $sheet->cells('A1:AK1', function($cells) {
                    $cells->setBackground('#fdc000');
                    $cells->setAlignment('center');
                    $cells->setValignment('center');
                });

                $sheet->setHeight(1, 30);
                $sheet->getStyle('A1:AK1')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);

                $sheet->setAutoSize(true);
            });

        })->store('xls');

        return "Generado en el Servidor -> Storage/exports/".$empresa.' - REPORTE VENTAS '.$mes.'-'.$anio."xls";
    }
```

Cualquier sugerencia, se agradece.

Comment: no te está faltando el parámetro $id cuando llamas al job? `$this->construirDataConcar($empresa, $tienda, $mes, $anio);`

Comment: No, me genera corectamente sin el Job, lo que descarto algun error de sintaxis o datos faltantes.

Comment: @DeyviDeLaCruz ¿Qué versión de PHP estás utilizando?

Comment: @AarónGutiérrez PHP 7.1 estoy usando Homestead como mi server local. hice un codigo similar para laravel 5.8 con php 7.3 y tengo el mismo error. hay algo en ese break y continue que no deja que se cree el Excel.

Comment: @DeyviDeLaCruz me parece que es un error de la librería que ya se corrigió, ¿intentaste ya hacer un “self-update”?

Comment: No puedo actualizar la libreria porque muchos modulos de reporte en la aplicaciones fueron programados con esa version, pero creo que ese fue el problema, hice una aplicacion aparte(en forma de api digamos) y use la version mas resiente y si pude generarlo, gracias por la sugerencia.